# Multi Tab Session - file manager

Tags: php, session, file-upload

I use Kcfinder file manager for uploading files on server. The file manager is enabled just for admins. I want to pass to kcfinder upload location through session. If admin is in page news files will be uploaded in a subfolder news, if admin is in page newsletter files will be uploaded in file newsletter.

How can I handle this for multitab? If the admin open in a tab news page and in another page newsletter then `$_SESSION["uploadURL"]` will contain the url from last open tab.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your session variable will be the url from the last open tab when the user opens your newsletter page in a new page.

If by 'page' you mean 'tab' then what you say will occur. But you could use a QueryString variable to solve this.

For example for the news page, a valid request should include something like:

```
 news.php?p=news (other another value pair)
```

You can use this to **decide** which will be the value of your upload destination directory.

Comment: File uploader is opened in popup window. So I need to find a solution to know from what page the request has come for file uploader.